# .net prevent keyDown on WebBrowser on certain keystrokes

Tags: c#, .net, browser, keydown, preventdefault

I write an application in Visual C# using .NET Framework 4.5 (Visual Studio 2012 RC Professional). In this application I have a WebBrowser element.

When I perform some keystrokes, such as `Ctrl + O`, instead of doing what I have told to my Form to do on KeyDown events, the WebBrowser handles the event itself.

I tried to do something with WebBrowser's `previewKeyDown`, but I am not sure what to do.

Could you help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should set `KeyPreview = true` on your hosting form .

Comment: The preview is successfully detected but the event propagates to the WebBrowser, while I don't want to

Comment: `To handle keyboard events only at the form level and not enable other controls to receive keyboard events, set the KeyPressEventArgs.Handled property in your form's KeyPress event-handling method to true.` [From MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute

PreviewKeyDown="WindowKeyDown"

```
    private void WindowKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.Key == Key.A && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("CTRL + A Pressed!");
    }
    }
```

look at this link
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx) or